# PlotOrientation of BoxAndWhiskerChart JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a question about `JFreeChart`: Is it possible to change the `PlotOrientation` of a `BoxAndWhiskerChart` to horizontal? I have a histogram, and I want to add a `BoxAndWhiskerChart` below. I need it horizontal so I can use the same axis scale. I tried to change the orientation in the `Plot` and `ChartPanel`.

[image: the look of my JFrame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Catalina Island shows the correct way to change the `PlotOrientation` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403070/230513), but you may run into a bug in the [`BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html) shown below for `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL`. Note the truncated line on the lower whisker.

[image: Original image]

The problem is [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/commit/726f7c4ace0e5dff6abe723c110fedd03b3dac52#diff-f3a7bb1ccbbfca0027072210bf9ff408) in `drawHorizontalItem()`:

```
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xxMin, yymid - halfW, xxMin, yy + halfW));
```

which should be this:

```
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xxMin, yymid - halfW, xxMin, yymid + halfW));
```

[image: Updated image]

Code as tested:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.statistics.DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407595/230513
 */
public class BoxPlot {


    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("BoxPlot");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset data = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
        data.add(Arrays.asList(30, 36, 46, 55, 65, 76, 81, 80, 71, 59, 44, 34), "Planet", "Endor");
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBoxAndWhiskerChart(
            "Box and Whisker Chart", "Planet", "Temperature", data, false);
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 300);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new BoxPlot()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Report & fix submitted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117622).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `PlotOrientation` on the `CategoryPlot` like this.

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
```