# How to run different version of JFreeChart in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

I am working on a project where I am trying to find some interaction between various bugs in JFreeChart project. However, for this I have to merge different files from different versions of JFreeChart and compile them as one project to see if there is some possible interaction between bugs. But I am finding it difficult to run multiple versions since different versions have compatibility with different java versions? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple version of [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) on your system, but only one will be first in the [`classpath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) when you build (`javac`) or run (`java`) the application. Here's one approach, in outline:

1. Download a target [release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/), e.g. `jfreechart-1.0.19.zip`.
2. Unzip the file: `unzip jfreechart-1.0.19.zip`.
3. Enter the directory: `cd jfreechart-1.0.19`.
4. Patch the source as desired, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407595/230513).
5. Build a new JAR: `cd ant ; ant -f build-fx.xml all`
6. Install in the IDE and test.